# AS 5.1.0 tomcat web.xml servlet load-on-startup not work

Tags: wso2

WSO2 AS 5.1.0 /wso2as-5.1.0/repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml . 
I add a new servlet in above path ,but when AS start my servlet not be loaded .
That could work on AS 5.0.1 , but not work on 5.1.0 . How could I do that in this version ?
Thank you .

```
web.xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
    <display-name>config Servlet</display-name>
    <description>config Servlet</description>
    <servlet-class>com.my.config</servlet-class>       
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop your own web application instead of modifying the mentioned web.xml. It is not recommended to modify that file.

WSO2 Application Server 5.1.0 comes with new [class loading environments](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Release+Information).

Please refer http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Webapp+ClassLoading

So, the recommended way to load your own Servlet is to develop your own web application. You can choose appropriate environment for your use.

Thanks!